# Create trigger to update column value when update or insert happens in the table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to writing mysql triggers.

here is the create sql statement

```
CREATE TABLE BRAND_PROFILE_MAPPING (
    PROFILE_MAPPING_ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DOTLOOP_PROFILE_ID BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    BRAND_PROFILE_ID VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PROFILE_TYPE VARCHAR(90) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PROFILE_NAME VARCHAR(225) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    SOURCE VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PROFILE_HASH VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ENTERED_DATE DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    CHANGED_DATE DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PROFILE_MAPPING_ID)
);
```

i created table based on above structure.here i have 2 fields   **ENTERED_DATE DATETIME 
    CHANGED_DATE DATETIME ,** date columns i want to write trigger if any insert operation both date fields should be inserted if there is any update operation,changed date field should be updated.
Appreciate your help.Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: can you share the table structure of `brand_profile_mapping_log` this table

Comment: why not use insert statement as `insert into brand_profile_mapping_log (PROFILE_MAPPING_ID BIGINT,DOTLOOP_PROFILE_ID BIGINT,BRAND_PROFILE_ID,PROFILE_TYPE,PROFILE_NAME,SOURCE,PROFILE_HASH)` values (NEW.profile_mapping_id,...)`

Comment: Use `timestamp` type instead of `datetime` in your create table  `ENTERED_DATE DATETIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` You don't need `changed_date` column for this table. You don't need to write trigger for this

Comment: we cannot change the data type its as per in prod environment

Comment: Are you creating the table? or already `BRAND_PROFILE_MAPPING` table is present with the create query above?

Answer (score 0):

Remove profile_mapping_id from list of values as it is auto incremental.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `brand_profile_mapping_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON brand_profile_mapping FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN insert into **brand_profile_mapping_log** values(NEW.dotloop_profile_id,NEW.brand_profile_id,NEW.profile_type,NEW.profile_name,NEW.source,NEW.profile_hash);
END
```

Comment: @Nithi In other words, you can not enter the value for a column that is auto-increment. Database will auto-populate it for you.

Comment: @Nithi did you get opportunity to review my observation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both columns to be populated by triggers you can do it in the following way

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER brand_profile_mapping_before_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON brand_profile_mapping -- you have to use BEFORE event
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.entered_date = CURRENT_DATE, 
    NEW.changed_date = CURRENT_DATE;

CREATE TRIGGER brand_profile_mapping_before_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON brand_profile_mapping -- you have to use BEFORE event
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.entered_date = OLD.entered_date, -- preserve the original value, so it can't be overridden
    NEW.changed_date = CURRENT_DATE;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8712/1)** demo